# Is a batsman out when the ball(hit by the batsman) naturally turned back to his stumps(but ball first went out of his crease)

Tags: rules, cricket

Is a batsman out when the ball naturally turned back to his stumps , but ball first landed out of his crease?

This happened to us when we played cricket last week , the bowler was a spinner , batsman hit the ball and it landed almost at the middle of pitch, then spinned(rotated) back and hit the stumps.

I was on the fielding side and we appealed for out!
but it was denied , and explanation was :

> A batsman can not be given out as the ball first landed out of his
>   crease.

Is there any rules like this ?

We were playing among friends(No official umpire).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would be out as explained in [law 30 - bowled](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-30-bowled/).

Simply put it has to touch something else on the field of play before hitting the stumps again for it to be not out bowled.

Comment: So this is an ICC approved rule ? (I don't know if www.lords.org is an official site of any cricket body. )

Comment: Lords.org is the website of the MCC who are responsible for the laws of cricket.  The ICC is just the body that organises international cricket.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marylebone_Cricket_Club